# Using URL Rewrite and HTTP together

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, web

I'm trying to use URL rewriting, but only on a part of the address, though I'm new to this area of web development and I'm a bit confused.

The address is: ***domain.com***/create.php?member=-1&hangout=1

But I'm trying to rewrite it to this: ***domain.com***/create/?hangout=1

I'm getting the correct page, though I can't access "hangout" with $_GET['hangout'].

This is my rewriting code in my .htaccess document:

```
RewriteEngine    On
RewriteRule    ^create/    create.php?member=-1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the `-1` in `member=-1` comes from, is that a fixed value ?

Comment: It is fixed, but it depends on the string before it. For instance: "create/" is "create.php?member=-1", whereas "display/" is "create.php?member=0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add your own query string in a `RewriteRule`, you must use the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag to append an existing query string

```
RewriteRule ^create/ create.php?member=-1 [QSA]
```

This will rewrite `create/?hangout=7` to `create.php` and add both `member=-1` and `hangout=7` as the query string.